# Load same Picker with different data depending on UIButton tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

I know, it is a very simple thing to do but I am running out of time, so the issue  is that I want to load Date Picker when  selecting/tapping a UIButton with tag=1 and load country list in picker  when  selecting/tapping a UIButton with tag=2.

I hope the scenario is very clear now, my motto is to create a single instance of UIPicker and depending on button tag show the picker with data.

I already have the data for the country list , country picker is  showing on my view fine but what to do when I have to load date in picker.

Any idea will be helpful.

***Note:-** I need a single picker for default DateTimeType Picker and a Picker loading country list .

Answer (score 0):

- On button click: Set a variable which will contain the last pressed button tag and call `[pickerView reloadAllInputViews]`.
- In your picker datasource methods, switch this variable and return the wanted values according to it.

For example:
`-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView    titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component    {
           switch (lastPressedButtonTag) {
               case 1:
                   //return something
                   break;
               case 2:
                   //return something else
                   break;
               default:
                   //we should not get there
                   break;
           }    }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but ' titleForRow:(NSInteger)row' method is  needed , when I will be showing country list from an array, but in case of showing date I just need to specify the pickertype to DataTimePicker, rest will be handled automatically. Hope you understand what I have asked.

Comment: I think that you should use 2 different pickers for dates and other contents since UIDatePicker is a subclass of UIPicker

Answer (score 0):

On button Click, set the enum which picker needs to load. Use the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thepickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
switch (thepickerView.tag) {
    case PICKER_TYPE_A:{
        return [arrayA count];
    }
        break;
    case PICKER_TYPE_B:{
        return [arrayB count];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return 0;
```

}

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thepickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

{

```
    switch (thepickerView.tag) {
        case PICKER_TYPE_A:{
            return [arrayA objectAtIndex:row];
        }
            break;
        case PICKER_TYPE_B:{
            return [arrayB objectAtIndex:row];
        }
            break;
        default:
           break;
       }
    return @"";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have mentioned I have to load date in picker, which we can show directly by specifying the pickertype to DataTimePicker. , why do I need a array for that.

Comment: In that case,you have to create two types of picker, one for date and other for city

Comment: I have already mentioned I need one instance, then you must read the question  before answering I think, but now you are saying now " create two types of picker".